# Send protocol buffer data via Socket and determine the class

Tags: c++, sockets, protocol-buffers

im working into Googles Protocol Buffers right now and have a question. If i have multiple .proto files and thus multiple classes, is it somehow possible when the data is sent over a socket to determine which type it is?

E.g. i have two classes, lets call them person.proto and adress.proto. Now I send one of those over the wire. How can the receiver determine wheather it is a person or an adress?

I am doing this in C++.

My attempt would be adding a frame around the message, containing length and type. But i want to know if there is already some kind of implementation for the type stuff, so i dont reimplement existing stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to detect which object was serialized, Protobuf don't do it. But you can handle that using protobuf very easy:

**1) Method:** just send message that has type and string body. To body you will serialize your objects, and in type you will show which object is serialized:

Something like that:

```
package MyGreatPackage;

message Pack
{
    required bytes packcode = 1;
    //code for data/query
    required bytes  mess = 2;
}

message Data
{
//anything you need to
}

message Query
{
//anything you need to
}
```

So, you will always send message Pack, where will be defined which object exactly is in "mess" field.

**2) Method:** protobuf allows this technique to achieve same thing without pack wrapper, look here: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques?hl=ru#union

```
message OneMessage {
  enum Type { FOO = 1; BAR = 2; BAZ = 3; }

  // Identifies which field is filled in.
  required Type type = 1;

  // One of the following will be filled in.
  optional Foo foo = 2;
  optional Bar bar = 3;
  optional Baz baz = 4;
}
```

So, you can set all classes you may send as optional and determine their types by required parameter.

Still, for me first varians seems better, choose what you like.

Comment: _'It is impossible to detect which object was serialized, Protobuf don't do it.'_ Note there is this [dynamic message mechanism](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.dynamic_message), but you'll need those descriptors I mentioned.

Comment: Thank you, that is third method, I didn't know about it :-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. Protobuf supports reflection using so called [message descriptors](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python/google.protobuf.descriptor.Descriptor-class).

But (as stated in the other answer) you'll need a reliable well known root message type. Instead of introducing your own message discrimination mechanism, IMHO it's better to use [protobufs extension mechanism](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#extensions)

Here's a sample of what we have in production

```
package Common.ConfigurationCommands;

message UcpConfiguration
{
     optional uint32 componentIndex = 1;
     optional ConfigCmdStatus configCmdResponseStatus = 2;
     optional string configErrorDescription = 3;

     extensions 100 to max;
}
```

The extension looks like

```
import "Common/ConfigurationCommands.proto";

message AmplifierConfiguration
{
    extend Common.ConfigurationCommands.UcpConfiguration 
    {
        optional AmplifierConfiguration amplifierConfiguration = 108;
    }
    optional uint32 preemphasis = 1;
}
```

---

```
import "Common/ConfigurationCommands.proto";

message FrontendConfiguration
{
    extend Common.ConfigurationCommands.UcpConfiguration 
    {
        optional FrontendConfiguration frontendConfiguration = 100;
    }
    optional bool frontendActive = 1;
    optional uint32 refInputComponentIndex = 2;

    extensions 100 to max;
}
```

You can check [this part of the documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp-generated#extension) to see how to deal with extensions in your C++ code.

Comment: Thats exactely what ive been looking for. Thank you!